# Django, Gunicorn, and Settings Dir

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I refactored an already deployed (and running just fine) Django project to use a settings directory instead of a settings.py file.  Project structure shown below:

```
project/
    app1/
    app2/
    project/
        settings/
            __init__.py
            base.py
            production.py
```

The server has stopped working.  I'm getting a 502 error.  I believe it's because gunicorn can't find the settings file anymore.  I've tried changing my wsgi file to use production instead of settings.

**wsgi.py**

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.production")
```

**production.py**

```
from .base import *
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["site.com", "ip"]
```

`base.py` is pretty much default with some static and media routes.

**Question**:

How do I tell gunicorn about my new folder structure so it knows the correct settings file to run.

**Edit**:

Upstart error: `gunicorn: Worker failed to boot.`

Second error: `Import Error: No module named project.wsgi`

Comment: what happens when you restart gunicorn? could you post your upstart file?

Comment: @dm03514 It immediately terminates with errors.  I updated the OP with two interesting ones.

Comment: @dm03514 I had an extra folder... there was an additional project folder wrapping the project...

Comment: Do you have a wsgi.py file in your project folder? If yes, open it and check the path of settings in there.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that your setting in wsgi.py is not working. You may try my way of specifying the settings module:

Under your project dir (dir that contains manage.py), run gunicorn with the command:

```
gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.production [project_name].wsgi
```

Replace [project_name]  with your own.

It worked for me.